# Exchange account with rogue permissions?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I am running Exchange 2003 and recently removed a former employee's mailbox. The email for this former user is userA@domain.com. This user had "Send on behalf of" privileges for userB@domain.com.

Now whenever anyone accepts appointments from userB, they get a bounce message trying to send email to userA. The userA account is not in any groups and has been removed from "send on behalf of" for userB, but the bounce messages still occur.

Is there a way I can search and find a rogue permission or setting in Exchange involving userA that is causing mail to still attempt to send to userA's old email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this before and it drove me crazy. I finally found this with caused with delegation. 
In userB's Outlook go to `Tools > Options > Delegates` tab. Remove userA from there.

Comment: As well check the permissions on userB's calendar.  If the user or dead SID is these will continue.

Comment: This was it. Delegates! They have caused pain in the past...

Answer (score 2):

Check the forwarding settings in the properties of user B's account - it's likely user A had user B's email set to silently forward to their mailbox.

Comment: Now I first thought this too, but the lack of NDR's for anything but appointments made me think otherwise.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, that doesn't make sense to me, either, so I kinda assumed that all they've noticed it for was appointments, but that it might be happening for everything.  How about it, Joshua - can you confirm that it's only for appointment messages?

Comment: It is indeed only for appointments...not regular email. Smells liked delegates, agh... I will find out in the morning. I did check that userB's mailbox was not set to forward to user A

Comment: +1 for the answer regardless